# How to range the x-axis from 1 to 20 with 5 difference each, in plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib-widget

This is the result of my code, what changes can be made ?
[image: this is the my code result, what changes can be made ?]

I want this as the result:
[image: I want this as result.]

Please Help.

Comment: Could you please add you code

Comment: If you post your code as text, it’s much easier to help, so I’d suggest doing that. It’s probably going to be `plt.xticks()` or `ax.set_ticks()` though depending on how you’ve created the plot

Answer (score 0):

Make use of xticks and numpy together and you can provide the steps:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(numpy.arange(0,21,step=5))
```

Sample output:

[image]